# Выделение первых пробелов после первого текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пример текста:

```
1:This     is a text.
2:I want to select the text
3:%^$ []*Previous space too
4:  The  ssspace before the text
```

В этом тексте необходимо выделить самые первые пробелы после любого текста.
В строке 1 - это пробелы между "This" и "is". Во 2 - один пробел после "I".
В 3 строке - один пробел между "$" и "[". В 4 строке пробелы между "The" и "ssspace" (но не самый первый пробел в строке)
Я недавно начал изучать регулярные выражения, поэтому не до конца понял как это реализовать. Включена многострочность (MULTILINE). 
Мой ход мыслей и само выражение: 
Выделяем один или больше пробелов, которые находятся после набора символов не равных пробелу, которые идут сразу в начале строки.

```
^(?<=\s*\S+)\s+
```

Проблема в том, что мое выражение вообще ничего не выделяет

P.S. это java (онлайн сервис)

Comment: Просмотр назад работать не будет при его неопределенной длине. Придется нужные пробелы ловить в группе захвата. Или, если это php, использовать сброс совпадения через `\K`.

Comment: Даже если это .NET, знак каретки должен быть внутри блока просмотра. `(?<=^\s*\S+)\s+`. PCRE: `^\s*\S+\K\s+`

Comment: Может, `(?m)^\h*\S+(\h+)`? Зачем нужно выделить эти пробелы? Что вы с ними хотите сделать?